# How do I pass a table as parameter on Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to pass a table as parameter on an ajax callback procedure in Oracle APEX 5, because I need to make an SQL query on that table.

The SQL process is stored as shared component inside the Apex 5 application. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zjZa.png)

My procedure is like this

(procedure name: THIS_PROCESS)

```
declare
    v_tablename varchar(128);--max table_name lenght
    v_ID number;

    v_somevar
BEGIN
    SELECT Columname, 
    INTO v_somevar
    FROM v_tablename
    WHERE ID = v_ID;

       --Do stuff           
END;
```

This code (FROM v_tablename) gives me a compilation error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I'm a total newbie. I had been reading that I should call that procedure with this javascript:

```
apex.server.process ( "THIS_PROCESS", {
        x01: "TABLENAME",
        x02: "Row_ID",

        pageItems: "#P1_Item,#P2_Item"
  },{
        success: function( pData )
            // do something here
        }
  } );
```

I do not understand why I should pass x01 and x02 instead of v_tablename and v_ID

Do x01 and x02 automatically are assigned to v_tablename and v_ID?

Comment: are you sure you connect to the true schema? ORA-00942 can be caused by this. i.e. perhaps your `v_tablename` is at another schema.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan The SQL process is stored as shared component inside the Apex 5 application. Do I need to do anything else?  https://i.imgur.com/d5xqkzo.png

Comment: sorry i don't know anything about apex but for oracle connection i could comment, there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example page process `THIS_PROCESS` of type "Ajax Callback". Note that you need Dynamic SQL to select from a table name that isn't hardcoded.

```
declare
    v_table varchar2(128) := apex_application.g_x01;
    v_id number := apex_application.g_x02;
    v_somevar varchar2(100);
    v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
    -- validate v_table parameter to avoid sql injection. will throw exception if it fails
    select table_name into v_table from all_tables where table_name = v_table;

    v_sql := 'SELECT Columname
    FROM ' || v_table || '
    WHERE ID = :A1';
    execute immediate v_sql into v_somevar using v_id;
    -- do something with v_somevar
end;
```

Do be careful with this sort of thing - this design will allow a malicious user to write their own javascript function which can pass any table name that it likes to your procedure.

Comment: I do not understand. THIS_PROCESS is already set in "Point" as Ajax Callback. I cannot write "create or replace procedure" there, because it throws a compilation error. I take it as that I should make 2 processes, but why I cannot use a single one, and write v_table := apex_application.g_x01

Comment: Oh, you can! My mistake, I misunderstood your question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you!. I spent a week googling it, and had no clue. Have a reward https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7p20NhyztxU

Comment: Take care using dynamic SQL without use of DBMS_ASSERT to validate the table name, you are open for SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic sql:

```
declare
    v_tablename varchar(128);--max table_name lenght
    v_sql varchar2(1000);
    v_ID number;
    v_somevar varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    v_sql := 'SELECT Columname FROM ' || v_tablename || ' where ID = :1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_somevar USING v_ID;

       --Do stuff           
END;
/
```

Comment: x01 is automatically stored inside v_tablename? or should I add the code  v_tablename := apex_application.g_x01   Oracle Documentation is confusing.

Comment: Thank you. You put me on the right track. Have a reward. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjfpW4A4wtM